# If else condition not working properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my code in which i want to display the book details taken from the book table.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="computer">  <!-- Branch Computer -->
        <legend> Computer Science</legend>
            <table class ="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> S.No </th>
                        <th> Book Name </th>
                        <th> Year </th>
                        <th> User ID</th>
                        <th> Owner Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <% @books.each do |b| %>                                       
                    <tr>
                    <% if b.branch == "Computer Science"%>
                        <td><%= b.id%></td>
                        <td><%= b.book_name%></td>
                        <td><%= b.year%></td>
                        <td><%= b.user_id%></td>
                                                    <!-- For displaying user details -->                             
                        <% @susers.each do |s|%>
                           <% if s.user_id == b.user_id %>
                                <td><%= s.address %></td>
                           <%else%>
                                <td><%"Not found"%></td>
                            <%end%>
                          <%end%>                           

                        <%else%>
                                <td><%"No any book of this branch"%></td>   
                        <%end%>   
                      </tr>                                     
                    <%end%>
                </tbody>    
            </table>    
        </div><!-- End of Computer Branch-->
```

But i dont knot what is going wrong here with the output?

It is displaying like this. Take notice of the long line of each row.
After editing i get this much. 
[image]

Ok this is something abnormal going on in the terminal

http://pastie.org/5134510
[image: Notice the second row.]
Thanks

Comment: could you maybe post your CSS, assuming the problem you're talking about is with the crazy lines going on with your table I believe the problem is in CSS. with classes table and tablehover and the sub-definitions of those (td,th,tr,tbody's)

Comment: actually those all classes are of twitter bootstrap. They just mentioned to use those classes where ever required.

Comment: line 31 needs <<tr>> and <</tr>> or put them outside of the if/else (after looking at @SachinParasad 's post)

Comment: Will you please tell me exactly what i need to edit. since line 31 is td tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified it to fix some problems with the table formatting.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="computer">  <!-- Branch Computer -->
            <legend> Computer Science</legend>
                <table class ="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> S.No </th>
                            <th> Book Name </th>
                            <th> Year </th>
                            <th> User ID</th>
                            <th> Owner Address</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <% @books.each do |b| %>
                        <% if b.branch == "Computer Science"%>                                       
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= b.id%></td>
                            <td><%= b.book_name%></td>
                            <td><%= b.year%></td>
                            <td><%= b.user_id%></td>
                                                        <!-- For displaying user details -->                             
                            <% @susers.each do |s|%>
                               <% if s.user_id == b.user_id %>
                                    <td><%= s.address %></td>
                               <%else%>
                                    <td><%"Not found"%></td>
                                <%end%>
                              <%end%>
                            <%end%>   
                          </tr>                                     
                        <%end%>
                    </tbody>    
                </table>    
            </div><!-- End of Computer Branch-->
```

as for the problem with the details, I am unsure as to why the bottom result is aligned to the right. Something I'd say was a CSS problem normally but why is it changing for each entry I don't know.

Comment: I pasted ur edited code over there but it is showing again some other type of display of that table. I just wanted to print the details of the book but since the owner details column is taking the details from a table.. for that i wrote this `<% @susers.each do |s|%>`
                               `<% if s.user_id == b.user_id %>`
                                    `<td><%= s.address %></td>`
                              ` <%else%>`
                                   ` <td><%"Not found"%></td>`
                                `<%end%>`
                            `  <%end%> `

Comment: Some how it is going in a loop.

Comment: ok I fixed it a little more looking at your new output. In terms of the bottom entry being over on the right I can't seem to figure out why that's happening. Try using the updated code (which should get rid of the extra lines at the top with the new code) and I'll keep looking for the problem.

Comment: i need to put up something suspicious going on in my terminal. How should i? it has large no of lines.

Comment: O_O is that what you got with my modified code?? wait you must have been getting that before-hand as well then right? That code tells me your if statement is ALWAYS false (for the details), are you sure that the id's are correct in the database?

Comment: Actually i changed my server.. Thin server i m using. so it displaying the whole process as far as i m getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076944/how-to-handle-each-iterator/13077185#13077185 Please see this link. i ve pasted each n every thing related to it. :(

Comment: Ok, but yeah (i edited the code again btw) you should look at the database-that terminal output makes be believe something is up with the database. Either that or the if statement is indeed not working.

Comment: sorry about disappearing on you-sandy storm hit. I don't know if I actually helped you but I'm glad your problem is solved :)